# Is it possible to filter only ProductVisualSearch from specified website in Azure Visual Search?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, bing-api

I have implemented a basic HTML version of Bing Visual Search from [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-visual-search/tutorial-visual-search-image-upload) tutorial.
I want to fetch only `ProductVisualSearch` from **specified websites**, is it feasible ?

Answer (score 0):

No, this `site` filtering features is not available for `Bing Visual Search`.

For classic images search, it is processed by adding a `site:` filter in the query (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/rest/api/cognitiveservices/bing-images-api-v7-reference?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365#filter-query-parameters)):

> q
>
> The user's search query term. The term cannot be empty.
>
> The term may contain Bing Advanced Operators. For example, to limit
> images to a specific domain, use the site: operator.

But as you can see also in Bing UX, this feature is even not available for similar image search directly on the website